# Anonymous Block Query for Related Column

Tags: apex, developer-console, debugging, execute-anonymous

I am trying to get the actual DeveloperName to display from the anonymous block code but all I can seem to get is the ID.

```
Contact C = [Select id, FirstName, Recordtype.DeveloperName from contact limit 1];
```

system.debug(C);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debug the actual field path instead.

```
system.debug(c.RecordType.DeveloperName);
```

When you debug a complex object, you are at the mercy of how Salesforce wants to coerce the data into a String. Another workaround is to serialize:

```
system.debug(JSON.serialize(c));
```

Serialization is a much more rigid construct and the engine won't omit properties unless they are transient.

Comment: Works Perfect.  I especially liked you including JSON in your answer and explanation.  Very helpful.